# Como corrigir Cross site scripting ou XSS

Tags: php, segurança

Estou estudando sobre algumas vulnerabilidades que encontrei em um site que fiz e me deparei com a possibilidade do invasor enviar código malicioso, pelo que li e por isso minha pergunta aqui, só preciso corrigir o meu script com um código parecido com esse:

Aplicação com vulnerabilidade:

```
$busca= $_GET[“busca”];
```

Aplicação sem vulnerabilidade:

```
$busca= htmlspecialchars ($_GET[“busca”]);
```

Somente com essa alteração é possível eliminar a possibilidade de ataque via Cross site scripting ou XSS?

Comment: Antes de mais, quem te disse que essa aplicação não tem vulnerabilidade ?

Comment: Olá @Edilson, como disse na pergunta, nas pesquisas que fiz, um dos sites que cheguei foi esse:
http://analistadequalidade.blogspot.com.br/2009/11/cross-site-scripting-ou-xss.html.
O que deu a entender é que simplesmente usando o código sugerido seria o necessário.

Comment: *htmlspecialchars* não escapa aspas simples *'*, e js em linha, aquelas no estilo *dom level 0* são ignorados.

Comment: Caso tenha tempo, e caso continue em resposta, lhe darei uma resposta com alguns exemplos em que o *htmlespecialchars* deixa que *js* seja injectado, ainda que reduzido.

Comment: Toda ajuda é sempre bem vinda @Edilson, agradeço.

Comment: Voce deve usar `ENT_QUOTES` e utilizar o `UTF-8`, nos dois parametros. No final terá algo como `htmlspecialchars($texto, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')`, um outro detalhe é se deve fazer isso antes (salvar no banco de dados já com o htmlspecialchars) ou se deve salvar "normal" e usa-lo na depois, na exibição. O segundo dizem que é melhor, porque evita que uma string seja "quebrada" pelo limite do banco. Para curiosidade o primeiro método é usado pelo Wordpress, que usa até MD5 e suporta até o PHP 5.2, ou seja  não é uma referencia de segurança.

Comment: Você pode santinizar o $_GET, $valor = filter_var($_GET[“busca”], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boa tarde,

A utilização do **htmlspecialchars** não irá resolver ataques de XSS sofisticados. Aconselho utilizar esse classe Anti-XSS que está mais específica:

```
<?php

class AntiXSS {
    public static $err = "XSS Detected!";

    /*
     * @function   : setEncoding
     * @return     : String
     * @parameters : str: Content you want to change the character encoding
     *               newEncoding: Character encoding you want set
     * @description: Convert the character encoding of the string
     *               to newEncoding from currentEncoding. currentEncoding
     *               detecting by function so you only need give str and
     *               newEncoding to the setEncoding function.
     */
    public static function setEncoding($str, $newEncoding) {
        $encodingList = mb_list_encodings();
        $currentEncoding = mb_detect_encoding($str, $encodingList);
        $changeEncoding = mb_convert_encoding($str, $newEncoding, $currentEncoding);

        return $changeEncoding;
    }

    /*
     * @function   : blacklistFilter
     * @return     : String
     * @parameters : str: Content you want to filter with blacklist
     * @description: Filter the content by blacklist method. Library use
     *               RSnake's XSS attack vectors. To add new attack vectors
     *               I'm continue to research.
     */
    public static function blacklistFilter($str) {
        if (preg_match("/<(.*)s(.*)c(.*)r(.*)i(.*)p(.*)t(.*)>(.*)/i", $str) > 0) {
            return $str;
        } else {
            return self::$err;
        }
    }

    /*
     * @function   : whitelistFilter
     * @return     : String
     * @parameters : str: Content you want to filter with blacklist
     *               whiteFilterPattern: Some patterns for filter the
     *               data types.
     * @description: Filter the content by whitelist method. To add
     *               new data types, I'm continue to research.
     */
    public static function whitelistFilter($str, $whiteFilterPattern) {

        switch ($whiteFilterPattern) {
            case "string":
                $pattern = "([a-zA-Z]+)";
            break;
            case "number":
                $pattern = "([0-9]+)";
            break;
            case "everything":
                $pattern = "(.*)";
            break;
            default:
                $pattern = "([0-9a-zA-Z]+)";
            break;
        }

        if(preg_match("/^$pattern $/i", $str) > 0) {
            return $str;
        } else {
            return self::$err;
        }
    }

    /*
     * @function   : setFilter
     * @return     : String
     * @parameters : str: Content you want to filter with blacklist
     *               filterMethod: Library have 3 method.
     *                  -Black Method
     *                  -White Method
     *                  -Gray Method
     *               filterPattern: Some patterns for filter the
     *               data types. (You can only use with whitelist filter)
     *               noHTMLTag: Use PHP's strip_tags function to
     *               remove HTML tags from content.
     * @description: Filter the content by method.
     */
    public static function setFilter($str, $filterMethod, $filterPattern = NULL, $noHTMLTag = NULL) {

        if (urldecode($str) > 0) {
            $str = urldecode($str);
        }

        if ($noHTMLTag == 1) {
            $str = strip_tags($str);
        }

        $str = strtolower($str);
        $str = addslashes($str);
    $str = htmlspecialchars(trim($str));

        switch($filterMethod) {
            case "black":
                $str = self::blacklistFilter($str);
            break;
            case "white":
                $str = self::whitelistFilter($str, $filterPattern);
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }

        return $str;
    }
}
?>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

Basta remover certos caracteres, como por exemplo <, >, &, ', ", /
Crie algum tipo de filtro, da pra utilizar o regex para fazer esse filtro.

$xss = /[&<>"'*]/;

De uma olhada no w3school de como utilizar o regex
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_regex.asp

no exemplo abaixo tem uma solução utilizando javascript, eu utilizei esse código no React (frontend), o filtro era realizado assim que o usuário digitava alguma coisa, só não esquece que colocar o filtro no backend também

```js
export const htmlPurify = (value = '') => {
  const regex = /[!@#$%^&<>"'¨¨*]/;
  return value.replace(regex, '');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Você tem uma opção não tão sofisticada quanto a do P1xM4, mas uma alternativa também é a filter_var:

```
$busca= htmlspecialchars ($_GET[“busca”]);
$strBusca = filter_var($busca,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_STRING);
```

Answer (score -6):

Basta bloquear caracteres especiais de serem interpretados no browser.

Alguns deles são < > ' ", etc.

Comment: Isso não tem o mínimo fundamento, irônico usar um nome que sugere ter relação com segurança. Seria bom estudar o que é o site (e ao menos ler o enunciado) antes de responder. Seguem alguns links que podem ajudar: [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70), [Answer]

Comment: Te mostro um dos meus sistemas e com essa proteção, e quero ver você conseguir fazer um XSS do mais inofensivo que seja. Provavelmente você nem responda, mas o desafio está feito =)

Comment: você está falando com quem já recebeu vários bug bounty por XSS, e não um entusiasta de fórum como você deve estar acostumado.

Comment: O problema aqui é que o site requer respostas ao que foi perguntado. Sobre o que você sabe ou não, aqui não é lugar pra discutir (e pouco me interessa, ainda mais considerando que não parece saber do que se trata a pergunta). Estou removendo os comments não relacionados ao assunto da pergunta e removerei esse aqui em breve. Uma lida em [answer] talvez ajude nas próximas respostas (e a [edit] essa se quiser corrigir)